# table of contents showing the title as only entry (laTeX )

Tags: table-of-contents

can you help me understand what's wrong with my tex file ?
i've recompiled multiple times but the table results still empty...

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\selectlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage{makeidx}  % Generazione index
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{url}


\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
    \kern 20\p@
    \hrule\@width \textwidth
    \kern 10\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \title{Segmentazione di immagini Tridimensionali Cammini Aleatori su Grafo di adianceza casuale}
    \author{
        Sergio Apreda \&
        Alessandro Cibelli
    }

    \institute{
        Università di Napoli Parthenope, Dip. di scienze e tecnologie, facoltà di Informatica
        Corso di Elaborazione delle immagini A.A. 2015-16 
    }

    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \input{00_Abstract.tex}
    \input{01_Introduzione.tex}
    \input{02_Concetti_preliminari.tex}
    \input{03_Stato_dell_arte.tex}
    \input{04_Metodi_e_tecniche.tex}
    \input{05_Risultati.tex}
    \input{06_Considerazioni_finali.tex}
    \input{07_Bibliografia.tex}

\end{document}
```

Has it something to do with the fact that i don't directly write in the file but use include instead ?

Comment: if your document stops after the table of contents then presumably there is an error after that, but you have only shown  the preamble before that which is presumably error free, do you get an error message? if not, have you got `\end{document}` in 00_Abstract.tex? (You say you use `\include` but appear to have used `\input`).

Comment: i meant input, sorry; and no, error message free. I've tried to change the class from llncs to article and it seems to work... any idea why ?

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.
A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4):

upon further research it appears that in llncs you have to insert this:

```
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        \makeatletter
        \renewcommand*\l@author[2]{}
        \renewcommand*\l@title[2]{}
        \makeatletter
```

after the class declaration line.